# Infer function argument type inside object literal in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, type-conversion, type-inference, typechecking

Given the code below:

```
type State<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (state: infer A) => infer R ? R : T[K];
};

type StateDef<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (state: infer A) => infer R ? (state: State<T>) => R : T[K];
};

function defineState<T>(initialStateFn: () => StateDef<T>): State<T> {
  // implementation that turns initialStateFn into State<T>...
}

const state = defineState(() => ({
  name: 'John',
  surname: 'Doe',
  fullName: (state) => state.name + state.surname
}));
```

My assumption was that, given the type definitions and the generic T argument, each type would be inferred like this:

`T` -> `{ name: string, surname: string, fullName: (state: any) => any }`

`State<T>` -> `{ name: string, surname: string, fullName: string }`

`StateDef<T>` -> `{ name: string, surname: string, fullName: (state: State<T>) => string }`

However that's not what seems to be happening and, in the end, the `fullName` function ends up showing an error because it's `state` argument is inferred as `any`.

Why can't TS correctly infer that the `state` argument of the `fullName` function is of type `State<{ name: string, surname: string, fullName: string }>`? Is there any way to make this work?

I also tried a few different approaches such as simplifying the `StateDef` type and introducing new generic types to `defineState` function

```
type State<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (state: infer A) => infer R ? R : T[K];
};

type StateDef<T, S> = {
  [K in keyof T]: string | ((state: S) => string)
};

function defineState<O, S extends State<O>, T extends StateDef<O, S>>(initialStateFn: () => T): S {
    // implementation that turns initialStateFn into State<T>...
}
```

But that didn't work as well

Comment: It doesn't work because you're trying to infer a generic type argument at the same type you're trying to contextually type a callback parameter and the two are dependent on each other.  The general issue is [ms/TS#47599](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47599) and the particular issue here is likely [ms/TS#53018](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/53018).  As for making it work, you'd probably need to refactor significantly; would you be interested in seeing an answer showing that?  Or just one saying "no you can't do this"?

Comment: I'm interested in a code that makes this work, even if that means significant refactoring of the initial code.

Comment: [Here](https://tsplay.dev/NdO50w) is one possible refactoring.  Shall I put that in an answer (along with the explanation for why what you're doing is not possible in TS as of now)?  Or am I missing something about the question?